# Open sets having open images in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $h:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ be a surjective function such that $\|h (x)-h (y)\|\ge 3 \|x-y\|$.

Prove that the image of every open set in $\Bbb R^2$ under the map $h$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$.

My question is that as the limit of the given function remains greater equals 3 so can it be proved continuous and 
Then as not every continuous functions show that image is open then??

Comment: hint: show that $h^{-1}$ is well defined and continuous. The latter statement then implies the claim by defintion.

Comment: How does continuity imply open sets??

Comment: Continuity of the inverse map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $h(x)= h(y)$ for some $x, y$ whe have, by assumption, $$0=||h(x)-h(y)||\ge 3 ||x-y|| \ge 0$$

which implies $x=y$, in other words $h$ is one-to-one, so $g:=h^{-1}$ is well defined. $g$ is continuous (even Lipschitz) since (note that $h$ is assumed to be onto) given $v,w $ we have unique $x,y$ such that $h(x) = v, h(y) = w$ so $g(v) = x, g(w) = y$, and
\begin{eqnarray}
||v-w|| &=& ||h(x) - h(y)|| \\ 
& \ge & 3 ||x-y||  \\ &=& 3 ||g(v)-g(w)||
\end{eqnarray}

If now $U $ is an open set then $h(U) = g^{-1}(U)$ is open since $g$ is continuous.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the bound